# Python dice roll game

Tags: python, dice

I'm making a dice game on python and I'm having an issue. "/roll1" and "/roll2" works perfectly but when I try "/score" it outputs nothing. How can I fix this?

```
#Autharisation
# password is any integer
while True:
    try:
        pass_word = int(input("Please enter the password: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    else:
        break

#Game

import random
def rolldie():
    
    inputChoice = input("Enter Choice: ")
    
    roll1 = ""
    if(inputChoice == "/roll1"):
      roll1  = random.randint(1,6)
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll1) )
      
        
    roll2 = ""
    if(inputChoice == "/roll2"):
      roll_2 = random.randint(1,6)
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll_2) )

    elif(inputChoice == "/score"):
      print(roll1 + roll2 ) 


    rolldie()
rolldie()
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: `roll_2` -> `roll2`

Comment: You are entering a new function after each input, so the variables `roll1` and `roll2` are different each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your function recursive, you have to pass your results from an execution to the next one, thanks to function parameters, for example:

```py
import random
def rolldie(roll1=0, roll2=0):
    
    inputChoice = input("Enter Choice: ")
    
    if(inputChoice == "/roll1"):
      roll1  = random.randint(1,6)
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll1) )
      
    if(inputChoice == "/roll2"):
      roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll2) )

    if(inputChoice == "/score"):
      print(roll1 + roll2) 

    rolldie(roll1, roll2)
    
rolldie()
```

You could also use a loop instead of the recursive way or use global variables but that is generally not the best option

Answer (score -2):

I tried the Code and I think I found a solution to your problem, hope it helps, hears the code:

```py
score1 = 0
score2 = 0

    

while True:
    try:
        pass_word = int(input("Please enter the password: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    else:
        break


import random
def rolldie():
    global score1, score
    
    inputChoice = input("Enter Choice: ")
    
    roll1 = 0
    if(inputChoice == "/roll1"):
      roll1  = random.randint(1,6)
      score1 += roll1
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll1) )
             
    roll2 = 0
    if(inputChoice == "/roll2"):
      roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
      score2 += roll2
      print("Nice roll! You rolled a {}!".format(roll2) )

    elif(inputChoice == "/score"):
      print(score1 + score2) 


    rolldie()
rolldie()
```